# Identify only the portion of EntryId that applies to an email (rather than the containing folders)

Tags: outlook, email, mapi

I need to identify unique emails from an inbox by storing the EntryId. I would like to save space on my unique index by only storing the portion of EntryId that applies to the message (rather than containing folders).

Can anyone confirm that it is possible to parse out the EntryId and retrieve sections that apply to only the email item? If so, which characters am I looking for (looks like the last 47, but I would like to validate that assumption)?

I am using Outlook 2007 with Exchange 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange entry id contains 4 bytes prefix, muid (16 bytes), source key of the parent folder, source key of the message itself.

If you are in online mode, you can retrieve the PR_SOURCE_KEY property of the message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using an outlook addin writein in C# and using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. Would I be able to find the PR_SOURCE_KEY from the Outlook.MailItem object?

Comment: Yes, you can access any MAPI property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty, but PR_SOURCE_KEY is only available in online mode - you can take a look at available properties in OutlookSpy if you click IMessage button.